# Scanf for two integers separated by space with Enter key interruption

Tags: c, scanf

I need to get two integers from the user separated by space. The problem is, that if they enter only one integer and press Enter I need to print out the message that they have to enter two values and ask them to do it again.

```
scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
```

This is how I scan for the input. This code is inside a while loop, so basically I keep asking them for 2 valid numbers. It works perfectly, however if I type only 1 int and press Enter key nothing happens until I finally enter the second integer. 
Making two scanf() is not a good idea because I need values to be separated by a space. 
Is there any other way to break scanf() if the user presses Enter key? 
I need to use scanf() only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to not use `scanf`. Instead, use a more appropriate function such as `fgets`, which reads a single line of input terminated by Enter. After you get the line of input, you can then use `sscanf` to extract the integers (or any other method you like).

The `scanf` function is almost never the appropriate choice for interactive input.

Comment: I have seen a lot of solutions to this problem but need to use scanf().

Comment: @Alex: Well, `scanf` simply doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: I guess this is definitely a downside of scanf. It waits until the user finally inputs 2 values. Will accept this advice not to use scanf.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &a);` consumes leading whites-space when scanning for an `int` and lacks the ability to distinguish space from enter `'\n'`.

So `scanf()` for the leading characters first

```
for (;;) {
  char buf[2];
  if (scanf("%1[ ]", buf) == 1) Handle_leading_space();
  else if (scanf("%1[\n]", buf) == 1) Handle_leading_enter();
  else break;
}
// Now scan for an `int`
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) Handle_int(a).
```

The above does not handle tabs, carriage returns, and other white space.

Alternative, just look for every thing that is not numeric.

```
char buf[2];
while (scanf("%1[^-+0123456789]", buf) == 1) {
  Handle_non_numeric(buf);
}
// Now scan for an `int`
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) Handle_int(a).
```

---

IMO, best to read with `fgets()` and then parse.  Not using `fgets()` might make for a code challenge, but is not a good restriction for real programs.

Answer (score 0):

scanf return value is an integer, you can check how many arguments were successfully scanned:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &a,&b) != 2) {
   // error case
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ . Read the return value documentation

Comment: I can only check this condition after scanf(), but in this case scanf() will never end if I will not input the second integer. If I only input 1 int I can press as many Enters as I want, this is the problem.

Comment: The return value of `scanf` is not helpful here because in the case where the user presses Enter after entering the first number only, the `scanf` function does not return. It only returns after the second number is entered.